# How can I draw 3D shiny glass balls/spheres and glass bricks?

Tags: graphics3d, visualization, version-13.3

I first hoped `MaterialShading` was suitable for this purpose, but there is not a choice named `"Glass"` in the included 16 possible materials. And further I found that it conflicts with and will override other effects, like `Opacity`, `Texture`, `Glow`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

MaterialShading is more about *reflection* of light from the surface. Glass implies more *refraction*, passing of light through. So using simple Opacity and color and  Specularity (as David G. Stork did in his answer) should be fine imitating glass. If you want to add some realism, like glass surface scratches, instead of MaterialShading use [Texture](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html) - it plays well with Opacity, Glow, etc. *Note, you can use different textures and it will change how objects below look and feel.*

Import some surface image:

```
texture = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ4xa.jpg"]
```

[image]

Now simply apply it to your graphics primitives:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3],Glow[White],Texture[texture,"Box"],#},Boxed->False]&/@
{Cube[],{Sphere[],Cube[]}}
```

[image]

Also, from details section of [MaterialShading](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaterialShading.html):

> "MaterialShading will override any color, Opacity, Texture, Glow or Specularity settings."

Answer (score 1):

```
Table[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Orange, Specularity[White, n], 
   Sphere[]}], {n, {5, 20, 100}}]
```

[image]